# How to use a window prompt as a currency reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I run this code it will just repeat doing window prompt "what currency do you use?", even once I enter a valid currency. I'm very new to js and react so sorry if this is really simple

```
import React from "react"

function Product(props) {
    const MoreInfo = () => {
        alert(props.product.description);
    }
    const UserCurrency = window.prompt("What currency do you use?")
    
    var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
        style: 'currency',
        currency: UserCurrency,
    })
    
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>{props.product.name}</h2>
            <p>{formatter.format(props.product.price)}</p>
            <button onClick={MoreInfo}>More Info</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Product
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn about react hooks, in this case: useState and useEffect

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

function Product(props) {
    
    const [userCurrency, setUserCurrency] = useState(null)
    useEffect(() => {
      const uc = window.prompt("What currency do you use?")
      setUserCurrency(uc)
    }, [])

 
    const MoreInfo = () => {
        alert(props.product.description);
    }
    
    var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
        style: 'currency',
        currency: UserCurrency,
    })
    
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>{props.product.name}</h2>
            <p>{formatter.format(props.product.price)}</p>
            <button onClick={MoreInfo}>More Info</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Product
```

with useEffect, the code will run only once when the component is mounted, if you pass an empty array of dependencies as a second argument.

Please read the docs, as this explanation is far from enough to understand what's at stake here

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: Thank you this is very useful but when I run that I get this error: 
›TypeError: (0 , _react.useState) is not a function or its return value is not iterable (/Product.js:5)
/index.html

Comment: are you importing useState and useEffect? check the first line of my code

Comment: Yes I just copied and pasted

Comment: what react version are you using?

Comment: React Hooks only came with React v16.8

Comment: Oh thanks I'm only using 16.4

Comment: either you update it, or have to use Class Based Components with LifeCycle Methods, if you want to keep track of state on a component

Comment: I upvoted your question as a courtesy so you can start building your rep. Please do the same for my answer and, if you see fit, accept it as the correct answer with the check icon